# UIAlertView with 19 buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am creating a pop up dialog box (`UIAlertView`). It works great, except I need to choose from 19 items, and the buttons do not automatically scroll and only five fit on the screen.

So, can I make them scroll? If not, can I put a `UIPickerView` in an alert view? Or, is there a better way?

Code so far:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Provider"
                                                message:@"Please choose your provider:"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"AT&T",@"Verizon",@"Sprint",@"Nextel",@"T-Mobile",@"Alltel",@"US Cellular",@"Virgin Mobile",@"Metro PCS",@"Boost Mobile",@"Cricket",@"Rogers(Can)",@"Telus(Can)",@"Bell Mobility(Can)",@"Fido",@"Virgin(Can)",@"O2",@"Vodaphone",@"Meteor", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: This is a usability *nightmare*. 19 buttons?! Are you out of your mind??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using a [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead. It will automatically scroll when you have a lot of items.

Comment: Sure it'll scroll, but it's still the wrong ui element for stuff like this.  He's not performing an action, he wants the user to *pick* something.  Therefore, he should be using a control that's more suited for picking, like, say, a `UIPickerView` or a `UITableView`.

Comment: Ok so how do I go about putting a UIpickerView in an alertview or pop up of some kind or dose it work that same way?  I cannot see in the apple docs that it works like a pop up.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way, it slides from the bottom of the screen. If you don't want that you should go with another option.

Comment: ok when i search for uipicker instead of spinner in alertview i find code.  Im asking the right question with the wrong wording.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't create 19 buttons. Instead, use [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).

Comment: Picker  ... Sorry thats what I meant by spinner.  But can you put this in an UIAlertview?

Comment: @Sabanim alert views are for alerts.  Selecting an item from a list is not an alert.  What about presenting it in modally in a view controller instead?

Answer (score 1):

In general, use [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a modal view of some sort.

In this particular case, you may be able to use the [CoreTelephony framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603). CTCarrier has a property [carrierName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) that is supposed to return the something similar to what you are asking for (as long as the device is connected to a cellular network).

Comment: True. I believe that this will return the network currently connected to. So if you have verizon but are connected to a alltel tower, it returns alltel not verizon which verizon is what I need.  This is the first solution choice however it dose not work for this case.  Thanks

Comment: @Sabanim: See the linked documentation: "The value does not change if the user is roaming; it always represents the provider with whom the user has an account". The major drawback with `carrierName` is that it will return nil if the device is in airplane mode or has no service.